# Qt GUI open a file using push button

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I need to create qt gui push button with line edit, where I press the button which leads to browsing a folder to find a textfile I want to import. The textfile will be parsed afterwards. I would prefer to use combobox but I have no idea how to browse the folder through gui. Perhaps something like QDir related stuff should work but please help.

Basically, I want to import/open a textfile using push button/combobox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is [QFileDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qfiledialog.html)

connect the `clicked()` signal of your `QPushButton` to a slot that performs:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
    tr("Open Text file"), "", tr("Text Files (*.txt)"));
```

Then you can parse the file using for instance [`QFile` and `QTextStream`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfile.html):

```
QFile file(fileName);
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
       return;

QTextStream in(&file);
while (!in.atEnd())
{
    QString line = in.readLine();
    process_line(line);
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to parse a file where each line contains 31 floats that you want to store in a `float data[31]`, I would first create the class:

```
struct FloatLine { float data[31]; };
```

Then store all the lines in a `QList<FloatLine>`, this way:

```
QList<FloatLine> floatLines;
QTextStream in(&file);
while (!in.atEnd())
{
    QString line = in.readLine();
    QTextStream lineStream(&line);
    floatLines << FloatLine();
    for(int i=0; i<31; i++)
            lineStream >> floatLines.last().data[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Well, now I get an error saying 'fileName' was not declared in this scope,  and 'process_line' was not declared in this scope. is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @user2730981 the first error was a typo in my code that I corrected. For the second, `process_line(line)` is just an example of the kind of things you would like to write. You have to replace it by your own code, to do what you want to do. A first working code to test is: `qDebug(line);`.

Comment: Thanks! I have my last question... If I were to store each line into float, how could I do it? Basically I have 31 float indeces each line and i wanna save them as data[n++]. I get an error that 'cannot convert 'float' to 'const char*' Right now, I have `while(!in.atEnd()){
        QString line_value = in.readLine();
        float data[31];
        int n = 0;

        while(line_value != NULL)
        {
            data[n++] = atof(line_value.toFloat());
            line_value = strtok(NULL, DELIMITER);
        }`

Comment: If I don't use `.toFloat()`, then it says cannot convert 'QString' to 'const char*'

Comment: I get an error: "template argument for 'template<class T> class QList' uses local type'MainWindow::on_moveButton_clicked()::FLoatLine'.. What does that mean? I never used QList before so I'm not sure of the proper usage

Comment: you mustn't write this line `struct FloatLine { float data[31]; };` inside your method. write it above main.

Comment: @user2730981 you mustn't write this line `struct FloatLine { float data[31]; };` inside your method. write it above main.

Comment: am i supposed to do something with teh struct FloatLine?

Comment: @user2730981 replace `floats` by `data` (I changed my mind later on the name...)

Comment: Wow thank you so much! i appreciate all your help. its been very helpful at this late hour here haha

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [QFileDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html), there are few example at that QtDocument.